# Windows 8 Metro SyndicationClient.retrieveFeedAsync in Javascript not actually Async?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying out the JS Metro Sample Code form Microsoft site. However, I discovered that somehow the retrieveFeedAsync didn't work. My code was copied/pasted from their site as follows:

```
var syn = new Windows.Web.Syndication.SyndicationClient();
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("Some RSS");
console.log("1********************onactive");
syn.retrieveFeedAsync(url).then(processPosts, downloadError);
console.log("2********************onactive");
```

From the JS console, I noticed that the 2nd log line never got displayed, while it's supposed to because retrieveFeedAsync should give a "promise" object and return immediately.

Anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever see the 2nd console.log?

Using the code below I'm seeing the request is async and the order of the events in the log is: before, after, success. Which is the order I would expect for an async request.

```
var syn = new Windows.Web.Syndication.SyndicationClient();
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
console.log("Before");
syn.retrieveFeedAsync(url).then(function (data){ console.log("Success:\n"); console.dir(data); }, function (error){ console.dir(error); });
console.log("After");
```